# Clicar num botão e fazer aparecer outro

Tags: android

Como que eu faço ao clicar no `botao1` e fazer o `botao2` e `botao3` aparecerem na tela? Deixei o `botao2` e o `botao3` `visibility = invisible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é simples de fazer, basta usar o `onClick` do `botao1` para fazer aparecer os outros?

```
botao1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener( ) 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v ) 
    {
         botao1.setVisibility( View.GONE    );  //desaparece o 1
         botao2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );  //aparece o 2 
         botao3.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );  //aparece o 3
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado... a lógica eu tinha de como era, só não sabia que tinha que colocar View mas obrigado.

Comment: Como assim? `View.Gone` é só um valor estático para usar na função.

Comment: essa parte que eu não sabia, eu pensava que era setVisibility(visible)

Comment: @Nathan quando for assim basta ver a API da função e já te aparece essa informação toda ;)